# Choice of Square size for Monte Carlo computation of Pi

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables, pi, monte-carlo

You most probably know the typical example of computing Pi by generating random points in a square with a circle inside and looking at the ratio of points inside/outside the circle.

In most of the examples, the side of the square equals the diameter of the circle, but now I am asked to find the optimal relative size of the circle and the square in order to make the convergence speed of the Pi estimate optimal.

I have the intuition that the optimal choice is that the area of the square is two time the area of the circle, such that the probability of each point to be inside the circle is $\frac{1}{2}$. However, I am having a hard time to prove this (if this is actually right).

Does anyone know how show it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Interesting question. I share your intuition. To begin looking for a proof you have to begin with a formal definition of optimality. Any ideas? You might want to start by working out the optimal strategy for monte carlo computation of the length of an interval. Of course finding the length is trivial. But is embedding your interval in one twice as long optimal for monte carlo?

Comment: Well my starting point was to see the problem as a binomial distribution, where you can get 0 or 1 if you are out or inside the circle and $P(X=1) = p$. Then I was looking at the variance of the estimate of $p$ as a function of $N$ and $p$ itself, but so far I didn't manage to get anywhere.

Comment: Also with a symetry argument I think it is licit to say that $p=0.5$ is the optimum, as $p=0$ and $p=1$ are equally useless.

Comment: I guess it's irrelevant because both circle and square 'scale' with $\displaystyle a^{2}$ where $\displaystyle a\ \mbox{is the}\ Circle\ Radius$.

Comment: @FelixMarin I think you have in mind the original problem, where the side of the square $l$ equals the diameter $d$ of the circle. In my problem you have a circle of diameter $d$ inside a square of side $l$ but $d \neq l$. They ask you the relation between $d$ and $l$ that will make the estimate to converge the fastest. You see that if $l \gg d$ the estimate will be very bad because most of the points will fall outside the circle. If all the points fall in the circle it will be equally bad.

Comment: @Rayamon Now I got the point. My fault. Thanks.